# Assets install command

Tags: symfony

I can't make install assets in web directory in my symfony project for the bundle
`Ecommmerce\EcommerceBundle` here is the `AppKernel.php` code

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{



public function registerBundles()
{

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();

    }

    return $bundles;
}

public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
}
```

Comment: what is the output error ?

Comment: I see no Ecommerce bundle registered

Comment: [LogicException]                                                             
  Trying to register two bundles with the same name "EcommerceEcommerceBundle  
  "

Comment: i entered the wrong code sorry

Comment: Why `Ecommmerce\EcommerceBundle` does not appear in your code? Please update your question by clicking on *Edit* below it.